# Designing a class that guarantees correct use

Tags: c#, class-design

I would like some suggestions on how to model a class.

The class has methods `A`, `B` and `C`. The methods are required to run in this particular order, but not all of them are required. One can call `A` and `B`, without having to call `C`, if desired.

Here's a possible solution:

```
public void RunA()
{
    A();
}

public void RunAB()
{
    A();
    B();
}

public void RunABC()
{
    A();
    B();
    C();
}
```

The problem is however, that I need to deal with the result of `A` before running `B` and the result of `B` before running `C`

The workflow then becomes this:

- Run `A`
- Deal with result of `A`
- Run `B`
- Deal with result of `B`
- Run `C`
- Deal with result of `C`

The way i designed the solution above, this workflow is not possible. I could allow `A`, `B` and `C` to be run individually, but then the order of operations is no longer guaranteed.

Is there a better way of designing this workflow?

**EDIT**

I've been asked:

> "Why must these methods be called in a particular order?"

To answer the question, I have to explain the setup. `A`, `B` and `C`, loosely translates into these steps:

- **A:** Convert domain models to DTOs
- **Deal with result of A:** Save any exceptions that occured during conversion
- **B:** Calculate and return some statistics about the DTOs
- **Deal with result of B:** Save the statistics
- **C:** Send the DTOs through an API
- **Deal with result of C:** Save status of submission

It is obvious that `A` is first in the chain. `B` and `C` might be interchangeable, but for the sake of the question, let's say `C` does not make sense before `B` has run.

`A`, `B` and `C` could in theory deal with their results themselves. It mostly boils down to storing information about the results. But what I am trying to achieve, is for the class to be completely unaware of where the results go.

Comment: Keep track of the calls and throw if they are called out of order. Then document the methods so it's clear to people using it. Then redesign.

Comment: There are many different ways to achieve that. Definitely don't use this design. One alternative (of many others) is to pass the result of `A()` to `B()` and then that result to `C()`. That way you can enforce calling order - `B()` cannot be called without a result from `A()`, etc.

Comment: Another option is to simply throw and exception if `B()` is called before `A()`. Similar to how you can't start a manual transmition vehicle (`B`) unless the clutch is pressed (`A`).

Comment: The best solution might be to change the method itself. It would be better if you were to post the code from your methods or a small example. The class is an issue, but certain models have very difficult solutions so you may need to edit your method to wait for the user to deal with the result before moving on. Since I’m not sure what your methods are, I can’t really help you but here’s as best a solution as I could come up with.

Comment: add boolean variables to class like (DidARan, DidBRan) and check DidARan before running B and throw a exception or call A() from B()

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you really have to ask yourself is "Why must these methods be called in a particular order?". I assume that, if B requires A to have been called, it's not because of "the principle of the matter". It's because A does some work that B requires. If that's the case, then I'd simply allow A to be called

```
public void A() { /* Do Work */ }
```

then in the B method, have something like

```
public void B() 
{
    if (!CanProcessB()) {
        throw new Exception("B is not ready, Call A first");
    }

    // Do your work here
}
```

Ideally, the "CanProcessB" private method does more than just check if A was called. It actually verifies that conditions are correct internally for B to be called. Presumably, A() will set something up internally that allows B to be called. Verify that thing and throw an exception if it's not ready.

This is the approach I'd take at least.

Edit:

It really seems like the root problem is that your class is doing too much. It seems like there are three "things" being done here.

Domain To DTO Conversion

DTO Statistics Caluclation

API Caller

Honestly, these seem like three different responsibilities, and if you're looking to implement SOLID design practices, I'd argue that they should be three separate classes.

```
DomainToDTOConverter
DTOStatisticsCalculator
ApiInterface
```

DomainToDTOConverter obviously takes in a domain object, and returns a DTO.
DTOStatisticsCalculator takes in that created DTO (so A would need to have been called), and returns statistics about it.
ApiInterface sends that DTO over the API.

These would be three separate classes that can be used independantly of one another, and also makes unit testing much easier

EDIT 2:

Ah, so if you want to ensure that the user gets statistics about the DTO, then you could return that as part of the DTO Creation process. So the DomainToDTOConverter uses DTOStaisticsCalculator, and returns both the DTO and statistics about the DTO once called. That way, you know that the user has received them.

Of course, you can't ensure that they use those statistics in any meaningful way though.

Comment: I edited my question to actually answer the question "why must these methods be called in a particular order". Maybe it clarifies why I am chasing this particular modelling.

Comment: Your suggestion is now very close to what I have. But my question still boils down to the same problem: Provided the three classes you suggest, how would I best ensure that another programmer does not skip using the `DTOStatisticsCalculator`, before using the `ApiInterface`? As you say, the classes can be used independantly of each other. But that is not allowed.

Comment: EDIT 2 gives me a "chicken and egg" kind of problem. It ensures that the `DTOStatisticsCalculator` is used, which is a problem solved. But it also takes away my ability to save exceptions thrown by the `DomainToDTOConverter`.

Comment: Why does it take away your ability to save exceptions?

Comment: The `DTOStatisticsCalculator` operates on a list of DTOs. For simplicity, let's say it returns the count of all converted DTOs. For the `DomainToDTOConverter` to use the `DTOStatisticsCalculator`, it has to operate on a list as well, so that it can feed it into the  `DTOStatisticsCalculator`. In some cases, conversion fails for a DTO. You can still run statistics for the rest of the list, but the error should be saved. This is not be the responsibility of `DomainToDTOConverter`, and should be handled elsewhere. But that requires `DomainToDTOConverter` to return the error.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but it sounds like you're saying that there are possible cases where the DomainToDTOConverter fails. That's fine. It can definitely return a list of errors or throw an exception or something, and have the caller handle what to do with those errors (log them, ignore them, etc.). Whatever is calling the DTOConverter should expect to receive some errors, and handle them appropriately, I'd think.

Comment: And maybe I just don't get it :). But yes, there are cases where `DomainToDTOConverter` fails. That is okay, and expected. But i do need to save information about these failures _before_ moving forward with the `DTOStatisticsCalculator`. I can't see how to save that information while still enforcing that `DTOStatisticsCalculator` is up next. Not unless I make it the responsibility of the `DomainToDTOConverter` itself to save any errors encountered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155857/discussion-between-carlos-rodriguez-and-treeline).

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to make use of the strategy pattern.

Create a common interface:

```
public interface IMethod
{
    int MethodSequence { get; }
    void RunMethod();
}
```

Then you can have your individual methods:

```
public class MethodA : IMethod
{
    public int MethodSequence => 1;
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ran Method A");
    }
}

public class MethodB : IMethod
{
    public int MethodSequence => 2;

    public void RunMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ran Method B");
    }
}

public class MethodC : IMethod
{
    public int MethodSequence => 3;
    public void RunMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ran Method C");
    }
}
```

Now create the context and run the methods in the order of their sequence:

```
public class RunMethods
{
    public void Execute(IEnumerable<IMethod> methods)
    {
        methods.OrderBy(method => method.MethodSequence)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(method => method.RunMethod());
    }
}
```

Your calling code becomes any combination of the methods:

```
var runMethods = new RunMethods();

runMethods.Execute(new List<IMethod>
{
     new MethodA(),
     new MethodB()
});
```